# having extra column in User class in parse.com?

Tags: xcode5, parse-platform

0
is it possible to save and retrieve data into/from User class (including UserName & Password & Email ...) from Xcode. As in the following example is explained, i want to have "city" column...

```
objectID   username  password   authData     city
--------   -------- ---------   --------    ------
B873Jkd    User1     ***                    Istanbul
8Jj382     User2     ***                    Paris
82j92jL    User3     ***                    London
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add many columns and then send and receive data to and from the user class.Keep in mind that to query users, you must use a `[PFUser query]` .

After reading your comment I updated the answer to this:

```
 PFUser *typeOfUser;

[typeOfUser setObject:@"istanbul" forKey:@"city"];

[typeOfUser setObject:@"turkey" forKey:@"country"];

//and so on and so on....this will save directly to your User class and not to a second user class.
```

Comment: thank you for the answering, but it doesn't save that data by these lines of codes `PFObject *typeOfUser = [PFUser objectWithClassName:@"User"];`  
`[typeOfUser setObject:@"city" forKey:@"Istanbul"];`  
`[typeOfUser saveInBackground];`

Comment: **Plus** i don't want to save and retrieve data from/into the second **"User"** class, i mean i want it to be saved into the class that has userName and Password.  **Like adding "City" while Sign Up**

Comment: You can save directly to the user class in parse.I updated my answer.

Comment: No problem, hope it helped.